# Android Build: Dex Jumbo Mode in Gradle

Tags: android, android-build

I am using following line in android ant build (project.properties):

```
dex.force.jumbo=true
```

Now we are migrating from ant to Gradle. Is it possible to get jumbo mode active in Android Gradle build?

Comment: Move the setting to `gradle.properties` is ok,  gradle.properties file is at the project path

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can modify your `build.gradle` file to include:

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
}
```

Please note that this option is only supported by the now deprecated DX compiler. The D8 compiler does not support this option. From AGP 7.0 (released with Android Studio 2020.3.1 - Arctic Fox) DX support is removed completely.

Comment: Had to **gradlew clean** before assembling.

Comment: Where is this build.gradle file? In the platform? What if I don't want to mess with the platform folder?

Comment: Although since AGP 7.0 the support for DX is removed, the 'jumboMode' property in the 'dexOption' remains available, but has no effect. The d8 compiler uses jumbo instructions on demand (if you have too many strings). Since it's not documented anywhere, this answer on google issuetracker seems to be the only reference mentioning that: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189354519

Comment: Great pointer @StanislavShamilov, thanks for this! It seems like we don't need to enable jumboMode anymore as the compiler will automatically handle large instructions

Answer (score 4):

Modify `build.gradle` in your module to add:

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
}
```

After that run `gradle clean` in your project root

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it possbile to set force jumbo in Gradle, but since Android Studio 0.2.4 you can enable it in Compiler -> Android DX Compiler -> Force Jumbo Mode.

Comment: Sure, but how do i enable Jumbo Mode in build files without ide?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this on Windows by changing the `dx.bat` in the build-tools and adding the `--force-jumbo` parameter as a default. Definitely a work around though - hopefully this will be addressed in the Gradle plugin.

Comment: You can see the current source code for the Android builder here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/AndroidBuilder.java. The jumbo flag is simply not supported. If you have a better solution to enable it, please provide it instead of downvoting a working work-around.

Comment: Why do you say that the jumbo flag is not supported?  In android source I see command.add("--force-jumbo").

Comment: Ah you are right. I will update the answer with the correct configuration for Gradle.

Answer (score -1):

Check your build tools. Update if necessary and try again.

Answer (score -1):

> this error means that your method have got over 65536

just add multiDexEnabled on default config at build.gradle
file

```
defaultConfig {
   ...
   multiDexEnabled true
   ... 
}
```

this way also work:
https://blog.csdn.net/H_O_W_E/article/details/77742907