# Execution failed for task ':app:dexBusinessApp1Debug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

it's my third day with this problem I worked on android studio, really I'm sick, I need to find a solution, this is my error :

> ```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexBusinessApp1Debug'.
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>   C:\Users\Euphor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat
> ```
>
> --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Euphor\AndroidStudioProjects\BusinessApp1\app\build\intermediates\dex\BusinessApp1\debug
>   --input-list=C:\Users\Euphor\AndroidStudioProjects\BusinessApp1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\BusinessApp1\debug\inputList.txt
>       Error Code:
>         3
>       Output:
>         UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
>             at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
>             at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>             at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>         UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompatKitKat;
>             at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
>             at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>             at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>         UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/content/Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener;
>             at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
>             at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>             at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>         UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
>         java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>             at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:569)
>             at com.android.dx.dex.file.MethodIdsSection.intern(MethodIdsSection.java:109)
>             at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:148)
>             at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>             at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>             at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

I tried to exculed module: 'support-v4' but it doesn't work, I tested all the solution in stackoverflow, I clean and rebuild, I added the Jar one more one, and alwys the same error, really I need help guys and Thnak's

```
dependencies {

    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:21.+') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm-src.jar')
    compile files('libs/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/paralloid.jar')
    compile files('libs/paralloidviews.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr250-api-1.0.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':Android-RSS-Reader-Library-master')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':Forecast')
    compile project(':headerListView')
    compile project(':library-sliding-menu')
    compile files('libs/panoramagl.jar')
    compile project(':paymentKit_lib')
    compile project(':ProgressWheel-master')
    compile project(':stripe')
    compile project(':UIL_library')
    compile files('libs/coverflowlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/notificationcompat2-1.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

the stack when I execut gradlew ....
    processing

```
com/google/android/gms/games/internal/IGamesCallbacks$Stub.class...

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:               
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)
        at com.android.dx.rop.type.Prototype.withFirstParameter(Prototype.java:370)
        at com.android.dx.rop.code.Rops.ropFor(Rops.java:1210)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.run(RopperMachine.java:490)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitConstant(Simulator.java:691)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:764)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:94)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:787)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:742)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:349)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
:app:dexBusinessApp1Debug FAILED          
:app:dexBusinessApp1Debug (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 2 mins 19.441 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexBusinessApp1Debug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\Users\Euphor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --verbose --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Euphor\AndroidStudioProjects\BusinessApp1\app\build\intermediates\dex\BusinessApp1\debug --i
nput-list=C:\Users\Euphor\AndroidStudioProjects\BusinessApp1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\BusinessApp1\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
        3
Output:

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
                at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
                at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
                at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
                at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)
                at com.android.dx.rop.type.Prototype.withFirstParameter(Prototype.java:370)
                at com.android.dx.rop.code.Rops.ropFor(Rops.java:1210)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.run(RopperMachine.java:490)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitConstant(Simulator.java:691)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:764)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:94)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:787)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:742)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:349)
                at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:280)
                at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
                at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
                at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


* Try:        
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dexBusinessApp1Debug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\Users\Euphor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --verbose --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Euphor\AndroidStudioProjects\BusinessApp1\app\build\intermediates\dex\BusinessApp1\debug --i
nput-list=C:\Users\Euphor\AndroidStudioProjects\BusinessApp1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\BusinessApp1\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
        3
Output:

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
                at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
                at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
                at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
                at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)
                at com.android.dx.rop.type.Prototype.withFirstParameter(Prototype.java:370)
                at com.android.dx.rop.code.Rops.ropFor(Rops.java:1210)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.run(RopperMachine.java:490)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitConstant(Simulator.java:691)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:764)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:94)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:787)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:742)
                at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:349)
                at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:280)
                at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
                at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
                at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\Users\Euphor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --verbose --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Euphor\AndroidStudioProjects\BusinessApp1\app\build\intermediates\dex\BusinessApp1\debug --i
nput-list=C:\Users\Euphor\AndroidStudioProjects\BusinessApp1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\BusinessApp1\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
        3
Output:

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021901/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-dexdebug

Comment: I tried all the solutions but always it gives the same problem