# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug:'

Tags: android, gradle, build, runtime-error

I have a problem with the build.gradle files
i got error like this.

```
     ****

        Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
            > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
        org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' 
    finished with non-zero exit value 2**

**
```

Build.gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app_id"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'jniLibs'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile group: 'com.tokbox', name: 'opentok-server-sdk', version: '2.2.2'
}
```

i make many chenges in my bulild.gradle but i can't get right one

here is my Build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

i don't know how to avoid this error Help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: visit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021901/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-dexdebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your file build. gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true 
  }
```