# Parse.com, Parse SDK download NO Parse-1.10.3.jar file in the SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, jar

I have done multiple kinds of troubleshooting to figure this out. To no avail. I am going mad trying to figure this out, its just not there. When I download the sdk and extract it from the zip, there is the bolt jar file, but not the regular parse jar file, however the properties file is in the sdk... just not the parse jar file..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

why you still use the old approach, as Parse SDK become [open source](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android) you could add SDK just by adding this line in build.gradle it's easier and cleaner.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
}
```

or if you prefer you can download [the latest JAR](https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.parse&a=parse-android&v=LATEST).

Comment: That worked thank you. But i still have issues with it showing as "registered". I followed their tutorial, and I'm confused.

Comment: they should update their https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing page

Comment: @wesleyfranks your code worked ? i am not able to get test push notification

Comment: I can't get my test device to "register" on their website. It won't do push notifications. I haven't tried any other services yet.

Comment: hey @wesleyfranks see if you have got any entries in your installation table in your parse.com's app

Comment: this is giving compile time error, `Execution failed for task 'app:dexDebug'`. Any ideas how to solve this? According to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19022328/1708390), this error will show if "_your jar files does not compile_"

Comment: make sure you remove the Parse Jare file if you add it before adding compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'  in Gradle 
because it will cause duplicated files.

Comment: Thanks, @humazed that is a good suggestion, I have since gotten my device to show as registered, and have moved on. I would suggest starting over with their tutorials, as there isn't much to do really. Using the compile method as suggested above, and removing the jar file did it for me. After starting over that is. Try it and let us know.