# app:dexDebug failed when building Android Projects

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, build, compilation

I keep getting this error when I build my projects in Android Studio:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And I have indeed turn multiDexEnabled, I don't get why this is happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021901/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-dexdebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a 65K exceed issue (though it kinda is) ... you need to check your module's **build.Gradle** file. The error occurs when you try to import many *similar libs at the same time*; clean your Gradle file Resync it & you should be good to go.