# Error:com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: java, android, gradle, dex

This is my build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.4.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile(name: 'identitytoolkit-api11', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile ([group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android', version: '1.21.0'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I use google endpoints and I generate the API libraries using this [doc.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool#generating_a_client_library_bundle_from_a_backend_api)
And include the jar file to libs folder.

I get this error and I don't even know how to get more info and what to do to come over.

**The solution:**

```
android {
    ...
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.4.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile(name: 'identitytoolkit-api11', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile ([group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android', version: '1.21.0'])
}
```

Comment: does your application extend `MultiDexApplication`?

Comment: No I don't think so.. Can you give me some more info?

Comment: I hope u have already seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021901/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-dexdebug check u r using duplicate libs?

Comment: please look at [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html), you will see that `multiDexEnabled = true` is not the only thing it mentions. It goes on further and says "In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element."

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Is it possible unused object in jar file cause the problem?

Comment: If you include `Google Play Services`, make sure you only include the module you need, because otherwise you'll almost immediately exceed 65k. ( `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'` ) https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution that I found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case I just replaced

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
```

because over 65K Methods were included.

Answer (score 1):

Check `multidexenable true`  in **defaultconfig** and have application class in you app and then --> extend it via `MultidexApplication` and use below line in your oncreate method of application:-

```
Multidex.install(this);
```

**EDIT:-**

--> also there is another line that if heapsize or gcoverhead exceeds issue occurs then below line will be usefull for you :-

```
dexOptions {
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: For the moment the correct solution is to include only the libraries needed.
Thank you, I will surely consider this approach if the limit is reached and beyond.