# Messages Gradle Build:Excution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.de.common.progress.ProcessException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

1.this code below is the issue:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

2.this code below is the app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.12'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.6.1+'
compile 'com.zhy:percent-support-extends:1.0.6'
compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.2.5'
compile 'com.bigkoo:convenientbanner:1.0.6'
//compile files('libs/cu_volley.jar')
//compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
//compile 'com.leaking.slideswitch:app:1.0.0'
compile 'com.bigkoo:alertview:1.0.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.bigkoo:pickerview:1.0.0'
compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'

debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3'
}

repositories {

mavenLocal()
maven {
    url 'http://xlab-tech.com:45682/mexus/content/groups/public/'
}
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
}
```

---

thanks for your resolving my issue.;)
i m a newbie for android, and at here i got many knowledge,thx everyone
.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021901/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-dexdebug)

Comment: @ELITE thx for ur suggest.  i know this issue' reason now, but i also get a trouble in my solution. you know, in the root of my project,there is a file which name is 'gradlew', how can i excute it? i used my terminal，failed.
{}

Comment: I have no idea about that..

Comment: i have solved my probable by delete app/build, and resync my gradle.thank u again @ELITE