# Compile latest google play-services as dependency in build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, google-play-services

Am using a Java plugin as I am building a very simple SDK for users to fire an HTTP request from their android phone.

My SDK is packages as a JAR which other users can import in their app and use the methods to fire the request.

I use Grade to build my project and get the Jar file. Until now, I was using a older version of Google Play-Services which had a jar file in my `android_home/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services-libs/libs`

But I upgraded my Google Play Services to latest version I see this path is no longer available. I see a new path and the packaging is changed to `.aar`.

I tried to follow some of the methods specified in this forum to convert this `.aar` file into jar and use it as a dependancy but when I unzip I could not see any classes.jar inside this `.aar`. I could only see `AndroidManifest.xml` and `R.txt`

I am unable to use `compile fileTree` option in Gradle. Please help me on how can I build my project or what modifications I need to do on my `build.gradle` file?

Current hack that I am doing is manually download the jar file from:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_3159130_r09.zip and using `compile fileTree` option. I need to get rid of this manual step.

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: Why not have your users import the Google Play Services dependency in gradle? https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project
They can simply add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`

Comment: Java and android plugin are not compatible. So they can't be used in a single gradle file right? Can you elaborate if my assumption of your answer was wrong. Thanks

Comment: Please check solutions given in this SO post - [Android Studio: Gradle - build fails — Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021901/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-dexdebug). I hope one of the solutions given helps.